# android SurfaceView onDraw Method Stop processing randomly

Tags: android, multithreading, view, drawing, surfaceview

I have created SurfaceView class for drawing on the view by onTouch method... i have read and learned some sample codes about the SurfaceView and Drawing Activity and created the following class:

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private DrawingThread drawingthread;
    public Paint mPaint;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    private float cx = 0, cy = 0;
    private boolean easer = false;
    private boolean touch = false;
    private Paint mEarserPaint;
    int count = 0;


    public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

         getHolder().addCallback(this);

    }

    public DrawingSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);

         getHolder().addCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        System.out.println("onSizeChange");
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        System.out.println("onSurfaceChange");

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        System.out.println("onSurfaceCreated");
        // For drawing that is called in the onDraw method
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xF0000000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);


        mEarserPaint = new Paint();
        mEarserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mEarserPaint.setDither(true);
        mEarserPaint.setColor(0xF0000000);
        mEarserPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mEarserPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mEarserPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mEarserPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);


        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

         drawingthread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
         drawingthread.setRunning(true);
         drawingthread.start();
         setFocusable(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        System.out.println("OnDestroy");
        boolean retry = true;
        drawingthread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawingthread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // on earser mode draw circal on touch
        if (easer && touch) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 50, mEarserPaint);

        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        // get the touch postion for drawing the circal
        cx = event.getX();
        cy = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            touch = true;
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            touch = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            touch = false;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        if (easer)
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }

    public void onAttributeChange(Paint paint, boolean e) {
        mPaint = paint;
        easer = e;
    }

    public Bitmap getDrawingSurface() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

And this is the thread class for SurfaceView:

```
public class DrawingThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder drawingHolder;
    private DrawingSurface drawingSurface;
    private boolean run = false;

    public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, DrawingSurface surfaceview) {
        drawingHolder = surfaceholder;
        drawingSurface = surfaceview;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        run = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = drawingHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if (c != null) {
                    synchronized (drawingHolder) {
                        drawingSurface.onDraw(c);
                    }
                }
            }finally {
                if (c != null)
                    drawingHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is working fine form the start but it stop drawing randomly on the view (not crashing) after while (between 5 sec to 3 min) when i keep drawing .. what i figure is that onDraw method stop processing and i don't know why, there is no exception in the log and the onDestory method is not called when onDraw stop responding to my touch's.

hope you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have the DrawingThread.  Your DrawingSurface class overrides onDraw and you call invalidate() to ask for it to be redrawn.  That should be sufficient to do what you are trying to do.

I would comment out the DrawingThread and see if it magically comes together for you.  I wrote a network whiteboarding app that started from the same sample code that looks like you started from.

Comment: When i remove the Drawingthread the onDraw method stop working at all the screen become black and i cant draw anything.

What i understand is the SurfaceView must use thread to work unlike the regular View so if there a way to implement SurfaceView without thread plz provide me some samples of how to do it

Comment: I see.  My app doesn't draw on a surfaceView but a class I wrote that extends from View.